# Ruby: list file names with special characters

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ascii, special-characters, iconv

I have a file as data/raw/sample�X�}.pdf. The file has special characters .

Now when I try to run the below code to list the file:

```
Dir["data/raw/*"]
```

It gives below output:

```
["data/raw/sample\357\277\275X\357\277\275}.pdf"]
```

i.e the special characters like � are getting converted to some octal representation like \357 .
Is there a way in ruby that can list the exact file with special characters.
Note- I m using Ruby version 1.8.7

Comment: “I want a ruby code...”—then you probably should write this ruby code.

Comment: I rephrased it. Can u let me know if there is a way.

Comment: This representation is an exact equivalent of `data/raw/sample�X�}.pdf`. You might try to `==` them.

Comment: Yup they are. But I need to list the files with special characters instead of the octal byte representation

Comment: Use `puts` or `p` or `print` or whatever. I do not understand what the question is.